SAS read table with special character in name passed through macro parameter
I don't know how to achieve to read table which has a special character # in the name and is being passed in as a macro parameter.
Here is a simple example:
%macro my_macro(p_lib=,p_table=);
proc contents data=&p_lib..&p_table. out=x; run;
%mend;
%my_macro(p_lib=tmp11, p_table=cso_list#703);
If I run that code it gives me an error:
33         tmp11.cso_list#703
                         _
                         22
                         200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, (, CENTILES, DATA, DETAILS, DIR, DIRECTORY, FMTLEN, LIB, MEMTYPE,

I have tried using quotes and quotes for literal names. e.g.
proc contents data=&p_lib.."&p_table." out=x; run;
AND
proc contents data=&p_lib..'&p_table.'n out=x; run;
But nothing really works. What am I missing here?

If you have you want to use non-standard names for MEMBERS you first need to set the VALIDMEMNAME option to EXTEND.  Then you can use a NAME LITERAL when referencing the dataset.
options validmemname=extend;
%let p_table=cso_list#703;
%let p_lib=tmp11;
proc contents data=&p_lib.."&p_table"n ;
run;

If you don't want to change the macro then make sure to pass member name as a name literal when you call the macro.
%my_macro(p_lib=tmp11, p_table='cso_list#703'n);

Are you really sure those are the names of your datasets?  What type of engine is being used by the tmp11 libref?  What do you see in the SAS log when you run this statement?
libname tmp11 list;


I have used validmemname=any. But I haven't tried with double quotes which seems to solve the problem ("&p_table"n).
The tables names are for sure named like that. The libname list gives me information about library.

<tablename>#<num> indicates you may be dealing with generation data sets

Definitions for Generation Data Sets
A generation data set is an archived version of a SAS data set that is created when the data set is updated. Multiple copies of a SAS data set are stored in a generation group, with each data set having the same root member name but with a different version number.
...
• Use the GENNUM= dataset option to reference a specific version from a generation group.

So, you can try
%my_macro(p_lib=tmp11, p_table=cso_list(gennum=703));

or, for the most recent generation use -1
%my_macro(p_lib=tmp11, p_table=cso_list(gennum=-1));


Didn't know that exists. I thought someone was generating such tables. I was getting some gennum errors as well at another piece of code. Thank you for that.
